# How in MySQL to specify a constant value for display?

Tags: mysql

I need to specify a constant value for a MySQL table's field (Manufacturer). Here is the example:

```
select cust_id as 'Customer Record ID', address_flag as 'Address Verified',
oem_manuf as 'Manufacturer'
from sales_db;
```

I want to have it return in the query that the field Manufacturer is set to XYZ Inc. How do I do this on the query without having to literally store XYZ Inc in each row for the oem_manuf field? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
select cust_id as 'Customer Record ID', address_flag as 'Address Verified',
'XYZ Inc' as 'Manufacturer' from sales_db;
```

Comment: Don't use single quotes to enclose [identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html)

Comment: What should be used? Why aren't single quotes OK?

Comment: @Edward Double quotes are preferable for Aliases with space. But single are syntax wise OK too. I just didn't change the ones you had and only changed what you needed

Comment: @Michel Those Quotes are around Aliases, not identifiers

Comment: @Hanky Panky I see, so the issue is the spaces. So to be on the safe side, I should change them to double quotes?

Comment: Yes because sometimes back ticks can be confused with single quotes and back ticks are used around identifiers, so yes more recommended would be to use double quotes around such aliases